# Facebook Graph API...how to get started?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to get a JSON file about the list of the friends of Bret Taylor ("btaylor" is a profile of Facebook used for practice). I am reading the Graph API official guide (on FB website) and I am undesrtanding that for this request I need an authorization token code.

I've found an access token code from the link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials
```

where I've wrote my aps id and secret code but if I try to open the following URL using the access token code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor/friends?access_token=MY_TOKE_AUTH_CODE
```

I get the following error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#604) Can't lookup all friends of 220439. Can only lookup for the logged in user (0), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

the token code is something like `access_token=112701417077438|GnwE4LeR_f_3r-mmxoi79ukgEFd`

Where is the problem? With Google I've found some tutorial with long php pages but following the official guide I can't understand how to use all of this code...on the official guide everything appear extrimely short and easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you need to set up your Facebook application. Go to the Developer App:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

During the process, you will get an App ID and an App Secret. Take note of them.

What to need to do next depends on the type of app you want to create, either a web app or a app on Facebook. You speak about Access Tokens, so I guess you want to create a web app.

Steps are here, it's pretty easy:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

You will need the infos gathered on the first step.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build a web apps. The apps should load the JSON file with the list of the friend of a specific user. I've already created the Facebook App so I have the ID and the secret code. I0ve made a logi-page as shown in your enclosed link but I'm still getting the following error "API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application." I

Comment: About the error message in your question, do you ask for the offline_access permission? For the new error, you redirect should be on the domain you declared in the App Domain field when you created your application in the Developer App.